# Youtube Extractor failed to resolve 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:master-SNAPSHOT'

Tags: android

i m getting an error i did everything but getting error is there any alternative solution for this
failed to resolve 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:master-SNAPSHOT'

i also did change master snapshot but problem didnot resolve

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

use 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v2.1.0'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but it will help someone. You need add following code in your build.gradle.

```
repositories {
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

I hope it help someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build.gradle and as @illusion said

```
implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v2.1.0'
```